# How to list all products using Shopp

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopp

Just trying to get a list of all products using the Shopp plugin for Wordpress. What am I missing? I can get a list of categories, and all products in each category, but products that aren't categorised don't appear.

Here's what I've got:

```
<?php
    $cats = shopp_product_categories();
    $dropdown = array();
    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) :
        $dropdown[$cat->slug]['group_name'] = $cat->name;
        $dropdown[$cat->slug]['group_items'] = shopp_category_products( $cat->id );
    endforeach;
?>
```

I'd also like to add a $dropdown['uncategorized']['group_items'] with an array of uncategorised items.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. :)

It ended up looking like this:

```
$cats = shopp_product_categories();
$cat_ids = array();
$dropdown = array();
foreach ( $cats as $cat ) :
    $cat_ids[] = $cat->id;
    $dropdown[$cat->slug]['group_name'] = $cat->name;
    $dropdown[$cat->slug]['group_items'] = shopp_category_products( $cat->id );
endforeach;

$products = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'shopp_product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'shopp_category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat_ids,
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )

) );

$dropdown['uncategorized']['group_name'] = 'Uncategorized';
while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
    $dropdown['uncategorized']['group_items'][] = array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
        'name' => get_the_title()
    );
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 5):

This simple solution worked great for me:

```
<?php shopp('storefront','catalog-products','load=true&show=999'); if ( shopp('collection','has-products') ) { while ( shopp('collection','products') ) { ?><a href="<?php shopp('product','url'); ?>"><?php shopp('product','name'); ?></a><?php } } ?>
```

Comment: there is a hardlimit of 1000 so setting show to 999 is redundant. The show option can be used in case you have more than 1000 products, or only want to show a few